# Add ability to "report abuse" on a cv

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Consider a cv that has material that is not worthy to show and it's set as public cv.  There needs to be a method to allow someone to "report abuse" allowing SO to investigate and flag / delete the offending cv.  I do not see this option - has it been considered?

Comment: How could a CV be abusive, exactly?  Other than to the person to whom the CV belongs?  Do you have a link to such an abusive CV?

Comment: Oh, I can think of a number of ways of making a CV abusive. What is deemed unacceptable in a SO profile, should arguably also be unacceptable in a CV. (There's probably a good argument though that if this ever actually comes up, an E-Mail to the careers team is more than enough.)

Comment: There isn't much that's considered unacceptable in a user profile.  Short of porn, hate speech and fraud, almost anything is acceptable there.

Comment: `porn, hate speech and fraud`  that was pretty much what I was thinking about.

Comment: If it's acceptable that is a clear indication that a "Report Abuse" is needed and should be there.

Comment: Aren't you always though @Pekka웃 ;)

Comment: Grrrr... must... not... upvote...

Comment: I would absolutely agree with necessity of this feature on the premise that abusive content in CVs is an apparent problem - do you have any examples? There's not much point in implementing features based on hypotheticals.

Comment: Ant P tomorrow could be a hypothetical.

Comment: @JonH I'm not sure what you mean - it's not really practical to implement solutions to problems that have shown no evidence of existing just because you can imagine they might one day exist.